# bash scripting add arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I have created a script which takes parameters and arguments. I want to insert the `--help` argument.

I already know how to parse normal arguments with `-`, but I don't know how to parse the `--` ones.

To parse options for `test.sh -h`, I use the following check:

```
while getopts ":h" opt; 
do 
case $opt in
    h ) {
            echo "help!!!"
            exit 1
    } ;;
esac
done
```

But I want to have the option to call the script with `test.sh --help`.

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 12.04… but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopts` cannot handle long arguments:

```
$ ( set -- --help ; while getopts -- -help opt; do echo "$opt"; done )
-
h
e
l
p
```

If you want to handle long arguments, you need to write your own parser.

The GNU version of `getopt` *does* support parsing long options, but you'd be better off not using it; it's not portable, and non-GNU versions have a tendency to break on certain types of arguments. For example, they often cannot properly parse arguments with whitespace in them.

Comment: Thanks. I have in the mean time found a solution in one of the shell scripts from /usr/bin :) I've edited the answer in my question

Comment: @bioShark Like I said, if you want to handle long arguments you need to write your own parser -- the script in your question is an example of that. :-)

Comment: There's no GNU version of `getopt`. There's a `getopt` in `util-linux` though which is likely the one you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided this solution:

> I found the solution in one of the .sh scripts from /usr/bin
>
> ```
>   if test "$#" -eq 1; then
>     case "$1" in
>       --help | --hel | --he | --h )
>         func_usage; exit 0 ;;
>       --version | --versio | --versi | --vers | --ver | --ve | --v )
>         func_version; exit 0 ;;
>     esac
>   fi
> ```

Chris Down's comments on it:

> Like I said, if you want to handle long arguments you need to write
> your own parser -- the script [that you found] is an example of that.
>
> For the record the script you found is badly written. For example, the
> `--version` partial match could be rewritten just as `--v*`)(assuming
> you're okay with `--vfoo`).